# Get IP addresses from Network Access

Tags: apex, setup

I want to get the IP address from `Setup` -> `Network Access` in my code, but I don't find a object to query, how can I query for it in `Apex`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The records are represented by the `IpWhitelist` object, but they cannot be queried for. How did I figure out the name of the object? Go to the edit view for one of them and pass its Id to the following in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
system.debug(Id.valueOf('05G000000000000AAA').getSObjectType());
```

I tried querying in the console with and without the `Tooling API` and got:

> sObject type 'IpWhitelist' is not supported.

Comment: Nice hack on how to get the sobject name. Great!

Comment: I do believe you can use the metadata API though, can't you? I haven't tried, but it seems to be the most appropriate place for such a setting.